# Can you "upgrade" Moxxi's gun?

Tags: borderlands-2

I read somewhere that if you tip Moxxi 15,000$, you get a gun. I did so and I got a corrode gun.

However, I was thinking that I should have saved it for 50. Is there any way to get that gun to level 50 or can you get another gun from Moxxi at 50 anyway?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As far as I know, no. The only way you can get a level 50 copy of Moxxi's Bad Touch "legit" without outside assistance is to donate to her for the first time when you're level 50. It's totally worth it, even if it means screwing yourself out of both that gun *and* the Good Touch for most of the second playthrough.

Do not despair though. You *can* rely on outside assistance.

Another "legit" way to get your character a level 50 Bad Touch is to level some *other* character of yours to level 50, then use the bank system to transfer it over to your "main" guy.

A less "legit" way to get your character a level 50 Bad Touch is to use item duplication with somebody who does have it. Duplication is simple:

1. You, on the receiving end, host the game.
2. Your friend, on the giving end, joins your game. Using windowed mode makes this easier.
3. Your friend touches a save point. In the save file the item is in his inventory.
4. Your friend drops the item to be duplicated.
5. Your friend quickly and forcefully closes the game (if you're using windowed mode click on the × button on the titlebar.) This discards unsaved changes.
6. You grab the item.
7. Your friends relaunches the game and reloads the latest save file, where the item is still in his inventory.
8. ???
9. Profit.

Comment: Is there a way to duplicate on PS3?

Comment: @Meraj99 - you could try 'turn off system' from the ps button menu, and if that doesn't work just yank the power cord out of the back of the system. not that I'd recommend doing it too often, and especially not whilst the hard drive is being read/written.

Comment: @Meraj99 If the duping goes wrong, well, you'll have the item and your friend won't. That means you can simply try one more time, switching sides.

Comment: @Robotnik Wouldn't picking "Turn off system" close the game cleanly?

Comment: @badp - Probably, but certain games I've played with auto-save functionality similar to Borderlands don't seem to save if I shut down using 'Turn off System'. I haven't got Borderlands on PS3 so I can't double-check if it is the same for it.

Comment: @Meraj99 pretty sure Quit should work just fine, you shouldn't have to shut down completely